# Returning only the first match using Regex Look-Behinds

Tags: c#, xml, regex, lookbehind, non-greedy

Given the following XML document:

```
<root>
    <myGoodSection 
          some="attr" 
          another="attr" 
      />
    <myBadSection yet="anotherattr" />
</root>
```

How can I return the first `/>` using Regex?  So far I've been able to get pretty close using the following expression:

```
(?ims)(?<=<myGoodSection.*?)/>
```

However, this will match every instance of `/>` that follows the first occurrence of `<myGoodSection`.  I've also tried combining it with a negative look-behind in an effort to make the expression non-greedy, but it does not seem to have any effect:

```
(?ims)(?<=<myGoodSection.*?)(?<!/>)/>
```

**Edit:**

I am using a tool built on top of C# to handle the regex replacement.  I do not have any control over how many matches I can use or not use like if I was using `System.Text.RegularExpressions` directly.  I reference C# here to clarify the features that the engine I am using supports.

Yes, I am aware that as a matter of general practice I should not be using RegEx to parse XML.  Let's just stipulate that given my current scope, requirements, and constraints that it is a perfectly acceptable solution (providing there's actually a way to accomplish it).

Comment: you must have seen [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) after 3 years of membership at SO.

Comment: That first answer was awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by replacing `.` with `\b[^>]` so that my final expression becomes:

```
(?ims)(?<=<myGoodSection\b[^>]*?)/>
```

That will only match the closing `/>` as long as the prefix does not contain `>` anywhere, which will then exclude all of the tags following the first match.

Comment: After I saw the updated question, I was going to make a similar suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First off you shouldn't use Regex to parse XML.

With that aisde, you can have it only return the first match using [Regex.Match()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx).

Also, if your regex is simply returning too much, you could use non-greedy selection, like so:

```
(?ims)(?<=<myGoodSection.*?)/>
```

*Note the `?` after the `*`.*

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify my use of C# in this case.  I'm not using it directly so I won't have the ability to say "Just use the first match" in C#.  I am also actually already using the non-greedy selection, but I left it out of my question by accident.